# How to Compare DateTime C# Months and weeks

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-2.0

I need to compare a date in C#
if the date is less than 12 months,i need to set a boolean value

My Code is

```
    String d  = "26/06/10";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yy", null);
    if ((dt > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)  ) )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is less than 12 months");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is more than 12 months");
    }
```

Is the best way to compare date in c#.
similarly i need to compare date is less than two weeks or not

Any help appreciated

Thanks

sup

Comment: I think what you are doing right now is the best way.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `TimeSpan` to get the difference between two `DateTime` values

```
String d = "26/06/10";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yy", null);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);

TimeSpan ts = dt - dt2;
```

You can use `ts.Days` to compare

Comment: even if you do use TimeSpan `TotalDays` would be appropriate instead of `Days`

Answer (score 0):

For two weeks:

```
if (dt1.Subtract(dt2).Days > 14)
{
    ...
}
```

For 12 Months(one year) (Considering day of the month is not important):

```
var monthDifference = ((dt1.Year - dt2.Year) * 12) + dt1.Month - dt2.Month
```

Comment: Wouldn't your second example be true if dt1 = 31 dec 2011 and dt2 = 1 Jan 2012. Is that what the OP really wanted?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. I put no thought on that. sorry for the silly answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);
  //Or if you want to neglect the time part you could do
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day,0,0,0).AddMonths(-12);
String d = "26/06/10"; 
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yy", null);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string res;

if (result < 0)
   Console.WriteLine("It is less than 12 months"); 
else if (result == 0)
   res = "is the equal";         
else
    Console.WriteLine("It is more than 12 months");
```

The problem with your code snippet is that it will output "It is more than 12 months" even if the date is equal.

Answer (score 0):

For a clearer understanding: you do not want to compare two dates (or DateTimes) but two **TimeSpans**. Namely the difference in time between *now* and the *date you supplied* - and the a time span of 12 months.

```
String d = "26/06/10";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan deltaTimeSpan = dt - DateTime.Now;      // get the time difference between now and the time given
TimeSpan twelveMonths = new TimeSpan(365,0,0,0); // get a time span of 12 months

// round the amount of days down and always supply a positive number of days
int deltaTime = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(Math.Floor(deltaTimeSpan.TotalDays)));

if (twelveMonths.TotalDays > deltaTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("It is less than 12 months ({0} days).", deltaTime));
}
else if (twelveMonths.TotalDays < deltaTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("It is more than 12 months ({0} days).", deltaTime));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The difference in time is exactly 12 months. ({0} days).", deltaTime);
}
```

Take note that this example certainly does not take in account leap years. The code does take in account weather the year to compare with lies in the past or the future (by converting the TimeSpan into a positive value and comparing against that one).

Adjusting the above code to do the same for two weeks or any other time span should be simple enough. Just change the TimeSpan I named "twelveMonths".

Comment: You can also use TimeSpan.Duration to ensure a non-negative TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)
if(DateTime.Compare(dt, date1 )
{
//provided date is within 12 months
}
else
{
//provided date is after 12 months
}
```